# Can i just send the http request I want? Every library seems to screw up something about this

Tags: javascript, angular, http

I feel like an idiot for not being able to get a simple HTML request to work after 12 years of being a web developer...

I am trying to hit a very janky 3rd party API.  This is the exact request I need make (with private bits redacted):

```
POST http://[redacted host]/Execute HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: text/xml
Authorization: Basic [redacted credentials]
Content-Length: 547
Host: [redacted host]
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)

<redacted-xml-body />
```

I can confirm this request works when hitting it via SoapUI.  If I try to use the Angular 6 HttpClient as below, it send the request as an OPTIONS verb, instead of a POST, and the API will have none of that.  **I know it's because of CORS**, but I need it to not do that, regardless (again, this API is janky).

```
    const options = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'text/xml',
        'Authorization': 'Basic R2F0ZUNoZWNrQHByZW1pZXItdXMubmV0OkdhdGVDaGVjayEh', // + this.loginService.loginToken,
      }),
      responseType: 'text' as 'text'
    };
    const xmlBody = builder.create(body).toString();
    const response = await this.http.post(url, xmlBody, options).toPromise();
```

I also tried `fetch()` and `$.ajax`, but they all seem to never send the exact right headers...

**Can someone show me how to send EXACTLY the request above from JS/TS in Angular6?**

EDIT: the API I'm hitting is really old and probably doesn't support CORS correctly in the first place, hence the reason I need to bypass the option request.

Comment: What do you mean "you know it's CORS"?  If your request is blocked by CORS then the destination server has to allow your request.  Nothing javascript wise can bypass CORS, nor should it.  It wouldn't be a security mechanism if it could.

Comment: You have to fix this from the server side, the reason why fetch sends an option request is to see which headers does your server allow. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) You need Access-Control-Allow-Origin and Access-Control-Allow-Headers headers to be propertly set on the server side.

Comment: If you don't control the endpoint use a proxy on a server you control or a third party service

Comment: It's true I don't control the server side. But when sending the above request directly from soap UI on the same source, the server accepts that request. I think it is actually when I go through a browser that it forces that option request first. Is there some way for me to force the browser to ignore that option request and just send the initial request?

Comment: @jrizzo the preflight request is part of the CORS protocol and is enforced by the browser. SoapUI does not run in the browser. Consider writing a thin API using Express or other light weight http server to proxy requests to the endpoints you are trying to access (that are not CORS enabled).

Comment: @terminally-chill  That's a good idea!  The API was originally consumed via a native app, not a browser based app, so that it how it was getting around this before.  Making a small "adapter" client to bounce off of would work.  I'd mark that as an answer, if you post it as such!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the preflight request is part of the CORS protocol and is enforced by the browser. SoapUI does not run in the browser.

Consider writing a thin API using Express or other light weight http server to proxy requests to the endpoints you are trying to access (that are not CORS enabled).